# How to find Max Date

Tags: c#

I work in C# using VisualStudio 2005 on Windows.  I want to find the max date between two dates.

Suppose:

```
From Date: 10-1-2009//Day-Month-YYYY
To Date  : 1-3-2009
```

I want to write a method which returns that "To Date" is the larger of the two.

Comment: This is obviously a homework question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230510/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @Adam somewhat less obvious given the original version.

Comment: I'm judging that based on the simplicity of the operation, not the wording of the question. You made it much more clear, but he is basically asking how to use comparison operators. This is programming 101 stuff.

Comment: I think this person is a beginner who has been asked to do things he has no understanding of, and on top of it, has very little understanding of English. Read all his questions and his answers, and you'll see. I think it's a lot _like_ homework, since he's being asked to do things he doesn't understand, but has to do them anyway. I just wish he'd ask a "friend in class", or pay the class genius to help him with his homework.

Answer (score 66):

Oh come on, this one is screaming to be a one-liner

```
public static DateTime Max(DateTime a, DateTime b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this on for size, no point in writing a Max routine ever again - use generics!

```
public T Max<T>(T value1, T value2) where T:IComparable
{
    return value1.CompareTo(value2) > 0 ? value1 : value2;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use Linq to Objects extension method `Max` like :

```
new [] {date1,date2,date3}.Max();
```

Comment: Wonderful solution.

Answer (score 5):

The DateTime class stores points in time numerically as a 64-bit integer value called a tick. **A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. [There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx#remarksToggle)**

Since `DateTime` is simply a numeric value, you can easily compare them as you would any two numbers using the `<` or `>` operators.

Comment: See AgileJon's answer: DateTime (and TimeSpan and DateTimeOffset) implement >, <, etc. so no need to extract the underlying value.

Comment: Didn't say you have to, just giving a little background on the DateTime class.

Comment: He doesn't need the background. He doesn't even need a clue. If you gave him a clue, he couldn't read it.

Comment: So? Our answers are useful to more than just the OP. Even if he doesn't benefit, someone might.

Comment: Oh come on! Never knew that you could simply compare between them! So silly of me!!! I was doing subtractions and even Expressions to find those values!! -_- Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static DateTime WhichIsBigger(DateTime first, DateTime second) {
  if(first > second) return first;
  else return second;
}
```

Or a real 1-liner:

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime, DateTime> whichIsBigger = (f, s) => f > s ? f : s;
```

Comment: ahh, Visual Studio 2005. Well someone can point out that the Func wont work there anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

Method that accepts any number of dates using params and System.Linq

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static class DateHelpers 
{ 
    public static DateTime MaxDate(params DateTime[] dates) => dates.Max();

    static void Example()
    {
        var date1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var date2 = date1.AddDays(1);
        var date3 = date1.AddHours(3);

        var myMaxDate = MaxDate(date1, date2, date3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler to do when you use `params`.

```
public class ExtensionMethods {
   public static DateTime MaxValue(params DateTime[] dateTimes) {
      return dateTimes.Max();
   }
}
```

You do not need to pass in the array. Call it with as many dates as you like:

```
var maxDate = ExtensionMethods.MaxValue(date1, date2);
var maxDate = ExtensionMethods.MaxValue(date1, date2, date3);
var maxDate = ExtensionMethods.MaxValue(date1, date2, date3, date4, date5);
```

Better yet, set yourself up for other mathematical comparisons at the same time by using generics:

```
public static T MaxValue<T>(params T[] values) where T : IComparable {
   return values.Max();
}

public static T MinValue<T>(params T[] values) where T : IComparable {
   return values.Min();
}
```

This generic option is why I posted in addition to Liran's answer.